# Vagrant VirtualBox inaccessible on osx

Tags: vagrant

I renamed my home folder, and my VirtualBox VM became inaccessible with the following error.

```
Runtime error opening '/Users/myusername/VirtualBox VMs/mysql_default_1418073752794_97780/mysql_default_1418073752794_97780.vbox' for reading: -102(File not found.).
/Users/vbox/tinderbox/4.3-mac-rel/src/VBox/Main/src-server/MachineImpl.cpp[731] (nsresult Machine::registeredInit()).
Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Machine
Interface: 
IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

I went into ~/Library/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml, and changed paths with no luck.

I then stupidly deleted my vagrant .vagrant folder. I successfully created a new vagrant instance and VM. I still have the old VM inside, ~/VirtualBox\ VMs.

How do I fix the path and point a new vagrant instance to my old VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found solution from a combination of online solutions. Because I renamed paths, and stupidly recreated a new vagrant VM, I had to reassociate the old VM with the new vagrant box configuration.

First, you have to grab the UUID from the old VM. In Mac OSX (Windows path may be different)

```
nano ~/VirtualBox VMs/<your vm>/<your vm>.vbox
```

In the XML look for the uuid

Paste that UUID into a file found inside your .vagrant folder.

example

```
~/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id
```

Open up VirtualBox, and remove the "inaccesible" vm entry, by right clicking and selecting remove.

Then add that same Virtual Machine. You should now be able to run "vagrant up"

Comment: Followed your instructions but instead got: `$ vagrant up
An unexpected error occurred while loading the Vagrant VMware
provider. Please contact support with the following
error code: '7'.
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

exit
`